# The inverse function of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to find the inverse of $e^{x^2}$? Or, if this is not possible,are there some functions that
approximate very well the inverse of $e^{x^2}$, especially when $x$ is very small and large?

Comment: *Hint* If $y=e^{x^2}$ is your function, solve this equation to give $x=$ some function of $y$. Think logarithms...

Answer (score 7):

If $y=e^{x^2}$, then $\ln y=x^2$, and $x=\pm\sqrt{\ln y}$. Note that if $y\ne 1$, there are two values of $x$ such that $y=e^{x^2}$, so $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ as a function on $\Bbb R$ does not have an inverse. However, if you restrict its domain to $[0,\to)$, it has the inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{\ln x}$, and if you restrict its domain to $(\leftarrow,0]$, it has the inverse $f^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt{\ln x}$.

Comment: I didn't think to take log of both sides. Your answer looks complete. Thank you.

Comment: @Abrilliantkid: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The classic "replacement":$$x = e^{y^2} \qquad \implies \quad \ln(x) = y^2 \quad \implies \quad \sqrt{\ln(x)} = y$$So $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{\ln(x)}$

**EDIT:** As commented by Frank McGovern, I'm assuming that the inverse function maps from positive to positive reals. As such, there is no inverse function. But you do have an inverse relation.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes $f^{-1}:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Brian is right as always. I have a tendency to neglect things.